# Angles between coordinate systems

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

1. We have two orthonormal coordinate systems in 3D, which initially are identically. We take 1. coordinate system and rotate firstly the x axis around z axis, so that the angle $\beta$ emerges. Then we rotate z axes of the 1. coordinate system around the y axes of the 2., so that the angle $\gamma$ emerges. What are the angles between a) x axes of the coordinate systems ($\beta '$), b) y axes of the coordinate systems ($\alpha '$).
   [image]

Comment: The question is not clear to me, also because you seemed to have interchanged $\alpha$ and $\beta$ between text and your sketch. It helps to use a standard sketch for your 3D system like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space. Do you mean that you start with 2 equal systems, say $C_1=C_2$, then rotate $C_1$ around the $z$-axis of $C_2$ and then around the $y$-axis of $C_2$? And then calculate the angles between the axes of $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, indeed I have switched the angles, now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first rotation the axes of $C_1$ become vectors $\mathbf{v_x}$, $\mathbf{v_y}$ and $\mathbf{v_z}$ in the coordinate system $C_2$. Assuming that all have unit length, we can directly see that after rotating $C_1$ around the $z$-axis of $C_2$ by an angle $\varphi_z$:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v_x} &= (\cos(\varphi_z),-\sin(\varphi_z),0)\\
\mathbf{v_y} &=(\sin(\varphi_z),\cos(\varphi_z),0)\\
\mathbf{v_z} &= (0,0,1).
\end{align}
$$
We then rotate these vectors around the $y$-axis of $C_2$ by an angle $\varphi_y$. This is a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R_y}$ so that the resulting vectors are $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{R_y}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ with
$$
\mathbf{R_y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\varphi_y) & 0 & \sin(\varphi_y)\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin(\varphi_y) & 0 & \cos(\varphi_y)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the angles between the axes of the systems. For the angle $\theta_x$ between the $x$-axis of $C_2$ and $\mathbf{w_x}$ we can calculate their dotproduct which gives us $\left(\mathbf{w_x},(1,0,0)\right)=\cos(\theta_x)$, and we simply get (using the rotation matrix) that $\cos(\varphi_y)\cos(\varphi_z)=\cos(\theta_x)$. For the $y$-axes we see that the roation around the $y$-axis does not change the existing angle $\theta_y$ after the first rotation, so we get in total:
$$
\begin{align}
\theta_x&=\arccos(\cos(\varphi_y)\cos(\varphi_z))\\
\theta_y&=\varphi_z.
\end{align}
$$